# Store REST-Credentials in Database

Tags: rest, authentication, encryption

I know that usernames and passwords shouldn't be stored in the database in a reversible form, but I need these credentials for accessing a REST-API over HTTP Basic Auth. Would it be secure enough to store an encryption key on the servers hard drive and use it to en-/decrypt the stored passwords or is there any other method to securely store passwords for REST-API's in a database.

Thanks in advance